# How to stop UIActionSheet blocking the UI when pressing multiple buttons?

Tags: objective-c, uiactionsheet

We are using the UIActionSheet-Blocks pod

https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UIActionSheet-Blocks

For some reason we find that if you press multiple buttons at the same time on the action sheet it will invariably lock up the UI.

I've tried to remove all code relating to handling button presses, updating and assured that there is no locking up of the UI.

It appears very fleeting, but it is certainly reproducable;

ie:

```
-(IBAction) filterSelected:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *buttons = @[NSLocalizedString(@"Item 1", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Item 2", nil)];


        [UIActionSheet showInView:self.view
                        withTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ActionSheet", nil)
                cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)
           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                otherButtonTitles:buttons
                         tapBlock:^(UIActionSheet *sheet, NSInteger index) {
                                NSLog(@"index = %d", index); 
                         }];
         ];

}
```

In this simple test I output a log.

When I run the app it will let me press one, or the other buttons I create.

But when I try to press multiple at the same time, it will lock the UI.

I tried doing dispatch_once, and other kinds of dispatching in case it was a dispatch or thread issue

Could you let me know if there is a way to solve this?